# junk value while reading in file.(Suspected junk value seems to be the word TextView)

Tags: android

This was just a simple program to create a diary of sorts. While reading from the file junk value of TextView(suspected) is present before the recorded text.None of the toasts show any junk. Help please

I'm getting an error while reading from this class

```
public class ReadDiary extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
    File file;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_diary);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String filename= intent.getStringExtra("example.mydiary");
        file=new File(this.getFilesDir(),filename);
        String data="";
        try {
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            int ch;
        while ((ch = r.read()) != -1)
            {
        data += (char) ch;
            }r.close();
        }catch (Exception e)

        Toast.makeText(this,data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        textView.setText("                ");
        textView.setText(""+data);
    }
}
```

The Class that writes to the file is

```
    public class DiaryEntry extends AppCompatActivity {
File file;
EditText editText;
String filename;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary_entry);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    filename=intent.getStringExtra("example.mydiary");
    file=new File(filename);
    if(!file.exists())
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Saved....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
         //   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Diaryentry);
    editText.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this,"Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
protected void saveData(View view)
{try {
    Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this,"Really?",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    String s="";
    s+=editText.getText().toString();
    s+="";
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new ObjectOutputStream(openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)));
    writer.flush();
    writer.write(s);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this,editText.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent= new Intent(this,DiaryHomePage.class);
    Toast.makeText(DiaryEntry.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
}
}
```